# dbvalue functions don't seem to be working on QGIS3

Tags: qgis

I've brought a project with some virtual columns into QGIS3, but the formula with dbvalue functions (from the refFunctions plugin) in doesn't seem to be working any more. It just gives NULL values. The relevant layer is loaded and nothing else has changed since bringing the project forward (it still works in QGIS2.16).

When I looked this up on the web yesterday, I remember reading something about the fact that QGIS3 has changed a load of APIs (whatever they are) and so the formula won't work.

Does anyone know a way around this? Is it that I can't even reference other layers in QGIS3 (which seems like something of a retrograde step), or is there just a new way of doing it?

Comment: What are dbvalues? Is that a plugin?

Comment: @ndawson Yes, sorry, I think it's part of the refFunctions plugin, but it's marked as compatible with QGIS3, I'm guessing it's just not, in which case the workaround bit of my question is the important bit.

Comment: Yes, that plugin is not compatible with 3. The plugin author just hasn't correctly populated the plugin metadata.