# Getting value from another table with dbquery

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to use `dbquery` to get a value from a table when a record in it is the same as a value in the source table.

In the table where I need the value-added (Sewerage_Manholes...) I am trying

```py
dbquery('asset','commision_date','GID_New=GID')
```

[image: example]

What am I not doing correctly?

I don't want to run a join by attribute in this case as if this works it opens up the opportunity to use complex SQL.

Comment: What field type is your column asset? I only see Asset_ID.

Comment: Both are integer. See the bottom table.

Comment: I cant see a column asset, just Asset_ID.

Comment: Yes it is the name of the table. I thought that's what's needed here. It is the first table in the screen grab.

Comment: Seems a typo in your second argument, `commision_date` against `commission_date` field.

Comment: It's not that either - I have also rechecked that both fields are integer. Is the structure correct... dbquery('table1','field1','matchfield_1_2=matchfield_2') where field1 is the field I want the value from, matchfield1_2 is the value from table1 to compare and matchfield_2 is the match column in the table it's being compared to.

Comment: I see your point and your structure is correct. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions/issues/3).

Comment: Just a thought: if 'complex' + 'SQL' is what you are looking for, the doors are wide open already, albeit elsewhere, with a different workflow: move away from keeping files on disk updated to managing only base data within a QGIS Project, and create and manipulate analytics and derivates as *Virtual Layers* via the *DB Manager*; export to file only when needed. *Virtual Layer* definitions are saved into the QGIS project file.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option as most clients need data in flat files. So if dbquery is not working is there a qgis equivalent to what works in Mapinfo/SQL for this simple case - {{ Add Column "Sewerage_Manholes_InspectionSh" (Asset_ID )From asset Set To cvr_number Where COL3 = COL78 }}

Comment: Is the third argument the right way round - should it be `'GID=GID_New'`

Comment: tried but it doesn't work -I found this bug report https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275008/dbvalue-functions-dont-seem-to-be-working-on-qgis3 and https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions/issues/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dbquery` won't work, this expression should (note the single and double quotes):

```py
attribute(get_feature('asset','GID',"GID_New"),'commission_date')
```

Be aware this will return `NULL` when there is no matching row in the `'asset'` table and will overwrite an existing date. I would first select all the features where 'commission_date' is null and then check the box 'Only update x selected features' in the field calculator.